# How to use index search in tableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my tableview names and title are comes from server through xml parsing as soon below figure.

[image: in figure1 name and title are comes from server through xml parsing]

In this tableview list I want to use indexed search which are as shown in the image below. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: you might need to have searchBox to search with alphabet matching and should display that particular array

Answer (score 0):

You can have Array of dictionaries where each section will be represented by dictionary object. The key for the dictionary would be the section Title and the value would be an array of rows in section.

You can use NSPredicate to search the returned array from server and construct the data source array. 
[NSPredicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

[iphone & Objective C - Filtering an array using NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999242/iphone-objective-c-filtering-an-array-using-nspredicate)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrData = Array<Any>()
var fromFilter:Bool = false
var arrStrData = Array<String>()
```

**Step - 1 :** Create UItableView in Your Story Board. - Datasource, Delegate

**Step - 2 :** import - UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource

**Step - 3 :** Implement methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell") as! MainCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    var dictData: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
    dictData = self.arrData[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]
    cell.lblName.text = dictData["name"] as? String ?? ""
    cell.lblEmail.text = dictData["email"] as? String ?? ""
    cell.lblAddress.text = dictData["address"] as? String ?? ""

    let image = dictData[""] as? String ?? ""
    cell.img?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "download.jpeg"), options: [.continueInBackground,.lowPriority], completed: {(image,error,cacheType,url) in

        if error == nil
        {
            cell.img?.image = image
        }
        else
        {
            cell.img?.image =  UIImage(named: "download.jpeg")
        }
    })
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```